# How to set the date of messages sent and received for exact time zone date time?

Tags: flutter, dart, time

I'm trying to create an app of messages but the problem is to order the messages if one of the user don't have the time correctly set ( for example with 1 less minute ). So how can I set a default time zone that I can set the date of the messages according to this time zone date time and not the local ( device ) time? I tried using Timestamp.now(), NTP ( idk if i used it correctly but it was getting local time too) FieldValue.serverTimeStamp(); ( that was returning instance and the date was not working ). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you save time take time in UTC like the following

```
DateTime.now().toUtc()
```

There can be one more issue in this approach. When a user has disabled automatic time setting and had manually adjusted time in the settings then it may result in inconsistent data too. To solve this you may try some api like worldclockapi.org. But there will be a small network delay to fetch time first then to save in your database. It's basically a trade off unless you have a server and save it in db taking time from the servers..

Comment: How can i use worldclockapi? because i've tried using final response = http.get(url) and used json do get the dateTime, but when i send the message for the first time it works but after that all the messages from user x have the same date time and all the messages from user y have the same time too. It looks like i have to use listener to the change of data because i just initialized the function but i dont know how to do that. can you help me with that?

Comment: On each message send you may have to fetch the time

Answer (score 0):

Use dart [ntp](https://pub.dev/packages/ntp) package to do this.

```
DateTime sendTimestamp = await NTP.now();
print('Send timestamp: ${sendTimestamp}');
```

Every time we need to send timestamp from device, just get it from `NTP.now()`.

Then to sync timezone between user app, use [timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) packages.

```
final detroit = tz.getLocation('America/Detroit');
final timeZone = detroit.timeZone(sendTimestamp.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
print(timeZone);
```

Comment: timeZone is not returning a date, how can i sync timezone between user app?

Comment: use [setLocalLocation](https://pub.dev/documentation/timezone/latest/timezone.standalone/setLocalLocation.html) and change all of your `DateTime` class to [TZDateTime](https://pub.dev/documentation/timezone/latest/timezone.standalone/TZDateTime-class.html)